# How to block websites temporarily?

Tags: websites

Is there a way to temporarily block websites in Ubuntu?

For example let's say ... Facebook (or any other website) is just available from 8pm or just for five minutes within e.g. two hours?

Thank you!

Comment: On unix.stackexchange, an answer to the question "[Two different /etc/hosts depending upon the time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41498/85530)"  explains how to have two versions of `/etc/hosts` called `/etc/hosts_worktime` and `/etc/hosts_playtime` and two cron jobs. One cronjob copies the given file to `/etc/hosts` at work time and the other copies the file at play time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The tool I'd recommend is [Get-Shit-Done](https://github.com/leftnode/get-shit-done). It edits your host file so that you cannot access blocked domains using any browser. However, it does not have a scheduler (although you could use `cron` for that).

[Stay Focusd](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji) is Chrome Extension that does something similar.

I personally use a secondary profile in Chrome, with the [Whitelist](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pocjkchlmhkjafdpmkklknmjhokobgmh) extension, so that it blocks all websites, other than absolutely necessary ones

Comment: Stay Focused is awesome!

Comment: Plus one for Stay Focused :D

Answer (score 10):

Open Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

Type `sudo -i` in the input field. Check the *Run in terminal* option. Finally click *Run* button.

Type your password if necessary and press enter. Then do the following command.

```
gedit /etc/hosts
```

You will get **gedit** Text Editor window.

For example, if we need to block Facebook just add the following lines just after `127.0.0.1 localhost`.

```
0.0.0.1 facebook.com    
0.0.0.1 www.facebook.com
```

By doing this, it will block the site in all browsers including Google Chrome, Chromium, Mozilla etc.... In fact, you can't access the website at all by any means.

That's it. When you now open **www.facebook.com** or **facebook.com**, you cannot access it. To enable back Facebook, remove the lines we added from the file `/etc/hosts` or as [Eliah Kagan](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan) said you can add a **#** character before the **0.0.0.1** text we added in **/etc/hosts** to make it a comment and to block it again just remove **#** character from the beginning of the line.

### Example

Blocking :

> 0.0.0.1 facebook.com

Enabling It Back by making the line a comment :

> #0.0.0.1 facebook.com

[Source](http://sag-3.blogspot.com/2012/09/block-site-in-all-browser-on-linux.html#askubuntu)

Comment: I know the terminal is great and all but is there a GUI for this?

Comment: @AvatarParto See this http://askubuntu.com/q/114415/87199

Comment: The block didn't work for `0.0.0.1 www.youtube.com`. Youtube was open in the web browser at the time. Probably due to DNS cache? I restarted networking with `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` and then youtube.com was blocked.

Answer (score 6):

If you use Firefox, the [LeechBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/leechblock/) add-on looks like it might do what you wish.

Comment: Does anyone accidentally knows a similar add-on for Chromium?

Comment: The link is broken, alternative on addons.mozilla.org [search/?platform=linux&q=leechblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?platform=linux&q=leechblock)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is important topic, so I've made python script to deal with issue
https://gist.github.com/josifoski/3d1406bba37694e19fce9d1e032bcb99

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu 20.04**

Open a terminal type `sudo nano /etc/hosts.deny` or with any editor in sudo privileges.

Then add all the urls you want to block

```
www.facebook.com
www.xxxxx.com
```

Save the file and reopen your browser