# Is there a GUI for /etc/hosts that I can use?

Tags: gui, hosts

I want to be able to easily and frequently edit my hosts file from a quick GUI. Any one know of one that exists?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [How do I edit configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160728/how-do-i-edit-configuration-files), [How do I edit the /etc/hosts file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343514/how-do-i-edit-the-etc-hosts-file),

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As already answered `hosts` is just a text file so you can use any text editor. Since it exists in `/etc` and you cannot edit as general user you need to use `sudo`. The graphical frontend to `sudo` is `gksu`. So basically doing gksu YOUR_GRAPHICAL_EDITOR /etc/hosts will do it OR you can use terminal with nano and vim. I recommend nano as it is quite easy.

`sudo nano /etc/hosts`

In order to ease the command you can use `alias`.

So edit your `.bashrc` file in your $HOME. i.e.
In your terminal do:

```
nano .bashrc
```

Add

```
alias edithosts='gksu YOUR_GRAPHICAL_EDITOR /etc/hosts' OR 'sudo nano/vim/vi /etc/hosts'
```

and save it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>. And do `source ~/.bashrc`. Then you can use `edithosts` from commandline to use it.

If you use unity you may use quicklist as well [What Custom Launchers and Unity Quicklists are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/what-custom-launchers-and-unity-quicklists-are-available)

Answer (score 7):

sagarchalise's answer is great, I also discovered gnome-network-admin which includes a pretty nice interface to edit hosts

```
sudo apt install gnome-network-admin
```

Comment: Perfect! As soon as you drop to terminal or require typing commands in alt-F2 you lose a lot of people who are not hardcore linux hackers...

Answer (score 2):

It's not a special editor as such, but you could always <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> `gksudo gedit /etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 2):

try one from electron apps - it has GUI, but need some manipulation with node.js installation - githab README.md has detailed info.
https://electron.atom.io/apps/?q=hosts

Answer (score 1):

Install this addon in firefox >>HostADmin 1.3.6 
It is awesome !!!