# How do I edit configuration files?

Tags: configuration, text-editor, editing

I'm a beginner to Ubuntu. Can anyone tell me how to edit a configuration file?

This is on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, please edit your post and provide more details, what do you exactly want to do?

Comment: Which files did you want to edit? I am asking because some files require root privileges and some highly recommend that you run a command specifically for editing them (example ```visudo``` for the sudoers file or ```crontab -e``` for adding cron entries)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get permissions to edit system configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92379/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-edit-system-configuration-files)

Answer (score 6):

Configuration files are usually owned by `root`. For example:

```
$ ll /etc/default/grub

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6801 Jul 18 13:26 /etc/default/grub

 ^^ ^  ^
 || |  +-- Users can only read
 || +----- Members of the group can only read
 |+------- The owner can write
 +-------- The owner can read
```

In order for a user (yourself) to edit `/etc/grub/default` you need to use `sudo` powers. So **instead of using**:

```bash
gedit /etc/default/grub
```

**You must use**:

```bash
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

At which point you will be prompted for your password.

**Note:** Related question today: [Grub file can't be saved after modification](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160777/grub-file-cant-be-saved-after-modification)

Comment: The answer depends on which configuration file you want to edit. Most are text files that can be edited with admin privileges. Some are not. For example Firefox configuration should be done from inside Firefox using `about:config` page.

Comment: @user68186 Yes there are all kinds of specialized solutions like you mention. However generically most of the default packages in Ubuntu require `sudo` to edit configuration files like `grub`, `plymouth`, `systemd`, etc. These are just examples of booting the system. There are many more applications after system is booted that also require `sudo`. I believe this to be the spirit of the question. Adding all the exceptions would make all the answers a textbook.

Comment: Fair enough. :-)

Comment: Rather than `sudo gedit`, isn't it better to use `gedit admin:///...` nowadays?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto In the old days I created `sgedit` script which copies users profile for gedit to root so I actually don't even use `sudo -H gedit` except buried within that script. i think there is a `gksu gedit` Q&A or two here in **Ask Ubuntu** where `gedit admin:///` would be a great answer for you to post. Please let me know when you do and I'll check it out.

Comment: I think I learnt about the admin prefix here on AU. Is there any specific place where you suggest I should post that as an answer? Do you mean this question or other questions?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto There are many questions about what to replace gksu with. Here's the one with my answer `sgedt` but it may not be the best place for your answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042344/i-need-an-equivalent-of-gksu-in-18-04

Answer (score 4):

System-wide configuration files, which are often in `/etc`, are owned by root and you need to elevate your privileges to edit them. It's common to run a text editor as root with `sudo`, and other answers here show how. But just because only root can make changes the files *does not mean you have to run your text editor as root*. **You can instead use `sudoedit`**, which is documented in [the same manpage as `sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/sudo.8.html).

For example, to edit `/etc/hosts`:

```
sudoedit /etc/hosts
```

The way this works is that `sudoedit`:

1. Checks if you've recently authenticated with `sudo` from the terminal you're in (like `sudo` does), an prompts you for your password if you haven't.
2. Checks if it is clear that could just edit the file normally, without `sudoedit` or `sudo`. If so, it gives you an error message and quits. (In this situation, [you should just edit the file normally as DK Bose says, assuming it makes sense to do so.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1160765/22949))
3. [Makes a temporary copy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/481884/why-is-sudoedit-writing-to-a-temporary-directory) of the file, opens that file in a text editor, and waits for the editor to quit.
4. Checks if the file has changed, and updates the original if it has.

**`sudoedit` works with your choice of text editor.** To edit with `nano`:

```
VISUAL=nano sudoedit /etc/hosts
```

It even works with GUI editors like Gedit:

```
VISUAL=gedit sudoedit /etc/hosts
```

Furthermore, **because the editor is run as *you*, it uses your configuration**, so if you've customized the behavior of your editor, those customizations are used. Other ways of attempting this [tend not to work very well](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications).

You can set the `VISUAL` environment variable [persistently for your user](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables) to make `sudoedit`, *and various other commands that need to pick an editor*, use your preferred editor. If you want to set an editor *just* for `sudoedit` (and `visudo`) but not other programs, set `SUDO_EDITOR` instead of `VISUAL`.

Because the logic of checking if two files are the same and copying one onto another is simpler than the full logic of a text editor--and especially simpler than the full operation of a graphical program like Gedit--running `sudoedit` *might* be considered more secure in the *specific* sense that it is associated with a smaller [attack surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_surface). Running less stuff as root is good. But the main reason to use `sudoedit` is convenience.

Because `sudoedit` is so useful and versatile, its benefits are sometimes overstated. It's a good tool, but you don't *have* to use it, and using it instead of other methods doesn't affect security in any *decisive* way. If you change system-wide configuration files in a way that breaks things, they will still break! That seems obvious when stated that way, but sometimes people try to give users the right to edit files owned by root with `sudoedit` while still trying to restrain those users in some way through technical measures. This is not usually practical.

Answer (score 3):

There are also configuration files in your home folder and its subfolders such as the *.config* folder. The preceding "." signifies the folder (or file) is hidden normally. Some config files may also be directly in your home folder. If you're using a file manager, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> will hide/reveal such files/folders.

Such files can be edited by a plain text editor with convenient GUIs (graphical user interfaces) similar to notepad in Windows. Editing such files should **not** require the use of *sudo* since you are the owner of these files. Indeed using *sudo* on files in your home folder is rarely, if ever, needed.

Some examples of plain text editors, most of them offering syntax highlighting, bracket matching, etc:

- gedit in Ubuntu
- mousepad in Xubuntu
- leafpad in Lubuntu 18.04
- featherpad in Lubuntu 19.04+
- kate or kwrite in Kubuntu ...

You could also use LibreOffice Writer but make sure you save your file as plain text and not in LibreOffice Writer's default Open Document Format.

Mostly though, you needn't edit config files directly. (That's why these files are mostly in hidden folders.) The preferred way is to use the GUI of whichever application your using. That way, you'll avoid making any "syntax" errors.

Comment: User-specific configuration files are common and this is a good answer. But while it is sometimes best to avoid editing configuration files directly, in some cases (e.g., `~/.vimrc`) manual editing is reasonable and recommended in official documentation. Configuration files are often named starting with `.` (or put in directories that are) because we don't usually want to be distracted by their presence (before `~/.config/` was in widespread use, home directories tended to have *many* dotfiles) and because operations we intuitively think of as "do X on all files here" should often skip them.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by WinEunuuchs2Unix, most of the configuration files are owned by root so typing "sudo" before the editor of your choice is necessary. I use "vim" to edit files so from the command line I type

`sudo vim (filename)`.

or if you use nano which comes with Ubuntu by default

`sudo nano (filename)`

There are many editors you can choose from; vim, emacs, gedit, nano, and many more.

Also, as I mentioned in my comment above it is recommended to run `sudo visudo` by itself if editing the sudoers file and also `crontab -e` when adding cron entries. Both of these commands will essentially open up the vim editor for editing files by default so I recommend getting familiar with vim but also exploring the other editors out there. It is very important to read the comments or notes at the top of configuration files to see if the system recommends against editing the files directly.

Comment: @user68186 added nano to my answer :)