# Grub file can't be saved after modification

Tags: grub2, files, configuration, wacom, text-editor

Every time I try to edit the grub file it does not let me save it. It says "access denied" or, in a different editor:

> Object not accessible. The object cannot be accessed due to insufficient user rights.

Sometimes it does not let me edit it, and this frustrates me as I need to edit it for my Wacom tablet to work.

How can I save my edited grub file? I saw a YouTube video on "Wacom on ubuntu: How to run your tablet on Ubuntu and Ubuntu LiveUSB - Wacom One" but I don't know if that works.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Which file are you trying to edit and what editor are you using. It's easier if you are trying this on a terminal as you can preceed your command with sudo to elevate your permission make the change possible.

Answer (score 3):

`grub` is a system owned application so you need to use `sudo` to edit the file:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

If you omit `sudo -H` you can view the file but not save any changes.

After editing the file you need to run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This will compile the changes you made to `/etc/default/grub` and compile them with `grub` functions to create a new `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` which is the actual file parsed at boot time.

**Note:** Related question today: [How do I edit configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160728/how-do-i-edit-configuration-files/1160748#1160748)