# How to block prefix+websites combinations temporarily?

Tags: websites

I was looking for a simple and effective way to block websites and
I really like [this simple soultion](https://askubuntu.com/a/193889/496493).

The problem is, you can block facebook with this modification:

```
0.0.0.1 facebook.com    
0.0.0.1 www.facebook.com
```

but users can still access facebook by going to `fr-fr.facebook.com` or other prefix+website combinations.

My question is, is there any way to include all possible prefixes? Virtually speaking, some patterns like `*.facebook.com`

Comment: The `/etc/hosts` way is quite hacky (also because you need superuser privileges for it) but I think you could append `0.0.0.0 *.facebook.com` to the file and that would work. See [here](http://superuser.com/a/220700/594841) for a full list of Facebook domains.

Comment: it is not working! but tnx anyways

Comment: Well, I use facebook as an example. I need to block many websites and try to find a solution for it  ...

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by configuring your firewall to block traffic in/out.

The network ranges in use by Facebook, which is your example turns out to be four subnets ( I've used `whois` to get them , there are many other methods ..)

```
31.13.64.0/18 
66.220.144.0/20
69.171.224.0/19
69.63.176.0/20
```

You can filter out those addresses by using `UFW` OR `iptables` so if you have UFW installed run :

```
sudo ufw reject out to 31.13.64.0/18 
sudo ufw reject out to 66.220.144.0/20 
sudo ufw reject out to 69.171.224.0/19 
sudo ufw reject out to 69.63.176.0/20
```

Else you can install it with `sudo apt-get install ufw` or just use directly iptables by running those commands with root access:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 31.13.64.0/18 -j REJECT 
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 66.220.144.0/20 -j REJECT 
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 69.171.224.0/19 -j REJECT 
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 69.63.176.0/20 -j REJECT
```

Comment: Can you add the exact command line of whois ?

Comment: first install with `sudo apt-get install whois` then `whois facebook.com` and read the output you'll get all facebook servers IPs .. I don't know if there is a better method to get the IPs though .

Comment: Do you know why there are also godaddy.com and google.com in the output of whois? isn't there a risk to block google with this method?!

Comment: Those godaddy.com and google.com are registrars .. a registrar is a server that register whois info .. there are no risk to block them